# Python does not output properly

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple ASCII FNaF game with Python, but it doesn't output from the coloring part of the colorama library.

Code:

```
import random
import time
from threading import Thread
#from keyboard import is_pressed
from colorama import Fore,Back
from os import system

dr1but = Back.RED
dr2but = Back.RED
battery = 100
showOffice = [0,34]
endCam = 0
rooms = ('Office','Toilet','Hall 1','Hall 2','Party Area','Kitchen','','','')
office = (
    "****************************************************************************************************************",
    "****************************************************************************************************************",
    "****************************************************************************************************************",
    "*******|||||| DOOR 1 ||||||****************************************************|||||| DOOR 2 ||||||*************",
    "*******                    ***************************************************                     *************",
    "*******                    ***************************************************                     *************",
    "*******                    ************ <------- Monitor -------> ************                     *************",
    f"*******                    *********** Battery :{battery}                ***********                     *************",
    "*******                    ***********                             ***********                     *************",
    "*******                    ***********                             ***********                     *************",
    f"*******                    **|{dr1but}OOOO{Back.RESET}|***                             ***********                     **|{dr2but}OOOO{Back.RESET}|*****",
    f"*******                    **|{dr1but}OOOO{Back.RESET}|***                             ***********                     **|{dr2but}OOOO{Back.RESET}|*****",
    f"*******                    **|{dr1but}OOOO{Back.RESET}|***                             ***********                     **|{dr2but}OOOO{Back.RESET}|*****",
    "*******                    ***********                             ***********                     *************",
    "*******                    ***********                             ***********                     *************",
    "*******                    ***********                             ***********                     *************",
    "*******                    ***************************************************                     *************",
    "*******                    ***************************************************                     *************",
    "*******                    ***************************************************                     *************",
    "*******                    ***************************************************                     *************",
    "*******                    ***************************************************                     *************",
    "*******                    ***************************************************                     *************"
)

for printOffice in office:
    print(printOffice[showOffice[0]:showOffice[1]])
```

Output:

```
**********************************
*******|||||| DOOR 1 ||||||*******
*******                    *******
*******                    *******
*******                    *******
*******                    *******
*******                    *******
*******                    *******
*******                    **|
```

I asked ChatGPT but it couldn't solve my problem.

I asked ChatGPT but it couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.